# How do I align a label vertical center in XCode 6

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6

Whenever I add constraints to the height and width of my UILabel, the text will then jump to the top of the controller.

How can I *vertically* center the UILabel in the ViewController?
[image: Image of contstraints]

[image]

Answer (score 37):

click on Align button on bottom toolbar in IB then select Horizontal or Vertical center. First you might want to fix width and height as well, if you want to preserve size.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

For an explanation of why this happens:

Whenever you add constraints to a view in interface builder you are telling IB that you want to opt in to auto layout and now you have to take full control of the layout.  The reason you see the label at the top of the superview is because you haven't added any constraints that determine the label's location within the superview.  See mohacs answer on how to add the constraints.

Comment: this really clarifies why it's happening and is useful, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone still need that here's how you can do programatically

```
let centerCoordinate = self.view.frame.maxY - (self.view.frame.maxY/2.0)
label.frame = CGRectMake(centerCoordinate,
100, 50, 50)
```

Comment: the question is about vertical alignment not horisontal